# PHP: Putting a string in alphabetical order

Tags: php, string

I'm currently making a website to list books, and I want artists/authors names to be in alphabetical order. I made something with php, but it breaks when there are more than 2 artists/author...
Can you help me?
phpfiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/se6p-wpw3

Code:

```
<?php
$artist = "John Doe, Ami, lolll";
if (strpos($artist,',') !== false) {
    echo "multiple artists\n";
    $artistchar = str_split($artist);
    $start = 0;
    $artistnum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($artistchar); $i = $i + 1) {
        //echo ($i)."\n";
        //echo ($artistchar[$i])."\n";
        if ($artistchar[$i] == ',') {
            echo "implode\n";
            echo ($i)."\n";
            echo ($start)."\n";
            $stop = $i;
            echo ($stop)."\n";
            $artistnum = $artistnum + 1;
            ${'artist'.$artistnum} = implode(array_slice($artistchar, $start, $stop));
            echo (${'artist'.$artistnum})."\n";
            $i = $i + 1;
            $start = $i + 1;
        }
        if ($i == count($artistchar)) {
            echo "implode2\n";
            $artistnum = $artistnum + 1;
            ${'artist'.$artistnum} = implode(array_slice($artistchar, $start, $i));
            echo (${'artist'.$artistnum})."\n";
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'only one artist';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link.

Comment: Where does your code put the artists in alphabetical order? It looks like all you're doing is reinventing `explode()`.

Comment: Just use `explode()` to split the string at commas, and `sort` to put that array in alphabetical order.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm new here :/ explode() didn't seem to do what I wanted earlier, but I'll try angain, and I haven't made the part where it classes everything in alphabetical order. But this should work just as explode(), or did I miss something?

Comment: There's no reason to use variable variables like that, use an array.

Comment: I haven't bothered trying to figure out if your code works or not.

Comment: I don't understand why you're incrementing `$i` inside the `if`. That will skip over a character after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$artist_aray = explode(',', $artist); // Split the input at commas
$artist_array = array_map('trim', $artist_array); // Remove the spaces around the commas
sort($artist_array); // Put them in alphabetical order
foreach ($artist_array as $a) {
    echo "$a\n";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! this is exactly what I wanted! Now I'm gonna hide in the Box of Shame because the answer was so simple

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
$artist = "John Doe, Ami, lolll";
if (strpos($artist,',') !== false) {
    echo "multiple artists\n";
    $artistarray = explode(',', $artist);
    asort($artistarray);
    var_dump($artistarray);
} else {
    echo 'only one artist';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do??

```
$artists = "John Doe, Ami, lolll";
$artists = explode(',', $artist); //slit the string
sort($artists); //reorder parts
$artists = implode(',', $artists); //put the string back together reordered
```